# Maximum Query Length in DelphiXE4 and MySQL Community 5.6.12

Tags: mysql, delphi, max

I use delphixe4 to send query to MySQL Community 5.6.12 database using ADO.
In one of tables there is many varchar fields and I'm worry about sending insert query cause it will be too long !

Is there any Maximum Length for queries?

```
f1:='This is a test !';

ADOQuery1.SQL.ADD('INSERT INTO MyTable (field1,field2,field3,.....,field30)VALUES('+QuotedStr(f1)+','+....+QuotedStr(f30));
```

Comment: don't concatenate your query, use parameters!

Comment: In some version of ODBC Connectors there were some problems with parameters and unicode data !

Comment: then change the connector, don't come back crying someone hacked your system!

Answer (score 0):

[**E.10.4. Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html)

There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table. The exact limit depends on several interacting factors.

So you do not have problems to add data on it (if you do not try to add more).
If Mysql accept this number of columms in a table, I think it is unrelated about Ado or other driver connector sql query.

Comment: Please add an indication (a mention of your source, with a link) when quoting from documentation. We have no idea where you got that information. Also, the question had nothing to do with the number of columns; it asked about the maximum length of a SQL statement.

Comment: There is also the limit of [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) bytes which you can send to the server at once and maybe others, but still, asking such question only indicates a design flaw.